# How to add methods when generating getters and setters to account for properties in JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, properties, getter-setter

Basically, I want to edit Eclipse in order to add something like the below code for the IntegerProperty absolutism when generating a getter and setter in order to add a getter and setter for both the value and property.

```
    public int getAbsolutism()
    {
        return absolutism.get();
    }

    public void setAbsolutism(int abs)
    {
        absolutism.setValue(abs);
    }

    public IntegerProperty getAbsolutismProperty() {
        return absolutism;
    }

    public void setAbsolutismProperty(IntegerProperty absolutism) {
        this.absolutism = absolutism;
    }
```

Comment: If you install the [e(fx)clipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse) plugin, it will allow you to automatically generate methods that match the standard pattern for JavaFX properties. If you wanted it to generate the non-standard methods you show in your question (which is probably not a good pattern to use, for a number of reasons), you would probably have to write your own plugin.

Comment: Your advice continues to be helpful in all aspects, I did indeed use the pattern available in e(fx)clipse as you suggested and adjusted to the standard pattern thanks.